# How to push an array into an array of objects using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, arraylist

I have this array:

```
$scope.arrayList=[{FirstName:"",LastName:""}];
$scope.Address=[{address:"",PhonNumber:""}];
```

and I want to push this another `$scope.Address` array into the `first(index)` object and the output should be like this:

```
$scope.arrayList=[{FirstName:"",LastName:"",$scope.Address}];
```

When I tried to push the address into the array it is creating a new object, 
so I tried this:

```
 $scope.arrayList[0].push($scope.Address);
```

But it's showing this error: "[0] is undefined"

Comment: HOW did you try to do that? Please add your attempt code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2c0q7pwp/1/ - looks fine

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why storing $scope.Address in $scope.arrayList. Can't you simply store array?

Comment: @nikhil actually i am getting the arrays dynamically but i am looping the another array into an object by specific applicationId

Comment: That is ok. What i mean is store the array corresponding to $scope.Address in a variable and then use the variable to assign the value to $scope.Address and update $scope.arrayList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
$scope.arrayList[0].Address= $scope.Address;
```

you can not insert array into an array of object without giving key/value pair.

Assuming `$scope.Address` stores an array of addresses for the `$scope.arrayList[0]`.

If that is not the case and you want to map each array with respect to the index, then try this:

```
$scope.arrayList[0].Address= $scope.Address[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot push into an object - only into an array. `$scope.arrayList[0]` is an object (person) not an array (address list). You have to define an array as property IN this object.

```
$scope.arrayList[0].addresses=[{address:"",PhonNumber:""}];
```

or you define the address list with the person object and use push

```
$scope.arrayList=[{FirstName:"",LastName:"", addresses=[]}];
$scope.arrayList[0].addresses.push({address:"",PhonNumber:""});
```